# How to save only the weights with lowest resulting error in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm working with Python 3.5 and Tensorflow 1.4 to create different kinds of neural nets. I use a cost function to train/optimize these nets. During training it may occur that the resulting costs stay on one level for some time or even rise but may decrease later on. So may problem is, that at the end of my training (given by a fixed number of epochs) my model may return a worse result than at some other point during training.

To always obtain the best known model weights at the end of training, I currently save my variables (`tf.Saver`) to a file during training whenever the costs are lower than the lowest costs before.

Unfortunately, this slows down the training process significantly. Is there any way to save all model variables to a python variable rather than to disk and restore them later on? I tried to do this with `tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.TRAINABLE_VARIABLES)` but I can't figure out how to get them back in my tensorflow model.

Thanks in advance!

UPDATE:

I found part of a solution. Instead of saving my weights as python variable, I create backup variables within the tensorflow graph. As far as I have got this has a drawback: As I implemented a lot of different graphs I have to adjust my solution to every one of them. Below you find a solution for a multilayer perceptron. But I don't know how to do this with a `tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell` for example. So I would prefer to have a solution that just saves all variables and let me restore them later on.

Current solution for a multilayer perceptron

```
# Prepare inputData
[...]

# Placeholder for tensorflow input
X = tf.placeholder("float", [None, len(netInputVariables)])
Y = tf.placeholder("float", [None, len(netOutputVariables)])

# Weights and Biases are stored in a dictionary
Weights = {
    'hidden1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([len(netInputVariables), 20])),
    'output': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([20, len(netOutputVariables)]))
}

Biases = {
    'hidden1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([20])),
    'output': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([len(netOutputVariables)]))
}

# Building the graph
hiddenLayer1 = tf.tanh(tf.add(tf.matmul(x, Weights['hidden1']), Biases['hidden1']))
yOut= tf.matmul(hiddenLayer1, Weights['output']) + Biases['output']

# Mean Square Error
CostFunction = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(Y - YOut))

# Training Operation
Optimizer = tf.train.AdadeltaOptimizer(learning_rate=0.1)
TrainingFunction = Optimizer.minimize(CostFunction)

# Save optimal weights
WeightsBackup = {
    'hidden1': tf.Variable(tf.zeros([len(netInputVariables), 20])),
    'output': tf.Variable(tf.zeros([20, len(netOutputVariables)]))
}
BiasesBackup = {
    'hidden1': tf.Variable(tf.zeros([20])),
    'output': tf.Variable(tf.zeros([len(netOutputVariables)]))
}

newCostLower = [WeightsBackup[key].assign(Weights[key]) for key in Weights] + [BiasesBackup[key].assign(Biases[key]) for key in Biases]
BackupWeights = tf.group(*newCostLower)

# Restore Operation
loadOptimalWeights = [Weights[key].assign(WeightsBackup[key]) for key in Weights] + [Biases[key].assign(BiasesBackup[key]) for key in Biases]
LoadOptimalWeights = tf.group(*loadOptimalWeights)

# Training
with tf.Session() as session:
    session.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    lowestCosts = 100

    for epoch in range(10000):
        _, costs = session.run([TrainingFunction, CostFunction], feed_dict={X: xData, Y: yData})

        # Save weights if costs have decreased
        if costs < lowestCosts:
            lowestCosts = costs
            session.run(BackupWeights)

# Restore bests weights at the end of training
session.run(LoadOptimalWeights)

# Do some kind of evaluation
[...]
```